# Data transfer from gridview column of one page to label of another page in C# where the gridview is autogenerated

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var firstCell = e.Row.Cells[0];
            firstCell.Controls.Clear();
            firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "ser_job_status1.aspx?Complaint_No = " + firstCell.Text, Text = firstCell.Text, Target = "_blank" });
        }
    }
}
```

I have used this to include hyperlink in my gridview.If that link is clicked it may take me to   ser_job_status1.aspx where Complaint_No is my table field name.
is it correct...
If correct how do i get that Complaint_No value in the Label field of my second page..
Kindly help me to figure it out...
I use C# in code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ser_job_status1.aspx page:

string strComplaintNo=Request.Querystring["Complaint_No"];
label1.text=strComplaintNo

or

Use Session rowdatabound page

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var firstCell = e.Row.Cells[0];
            Session["ComplaintNo"]=firstCell.text;
            firstCell.Controls.Clear();
            firstCell.Controls.Add(new HyperLink { NavigateUrl = "ser_job_status1.aspx?Complaint_No = " + firstCell.Text, Text = firstCell.Text, Target = "_blank" });
        }
    }
}

In ser_job_status1.aspx page:
label1.text=convert.tostring(Session["ComplaintNo"]);

Comment: Thanks Sai Ayyapps sekaran.. I tried out.. i am able to pass the value but not able to fetch the value in second page...kindly help me

Comment: ya i got now i am able to fetch Complaint_no value in second page but still it is not working properly . the label field in the second page fetches Complaint _No value which is bound at last to the gridview rather fetching hyperlinked value..